# Start a new query when the result ended

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

it's anyway possible to start (automatically) in the same column a new query when the first condition ends.

I needed something like the result in column K:R but now i have to write the formula everytime the condition R="end". I need the google sheet automatically to do it if possible

or other suggestion to have the same result: list of names (B) by user (H) with the condition the countries each user added (G:H).

Hope someone can help!

TY

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GdL5psaLKDix7282AZXGvZJUlm7rfhU2x5KlKTjp6ig/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. I deleted all information from that sheet that was not involved in the solution, in order to make things as visually clear as possible. I entered one formula, in L1:

`=ArrayFormula({"User"\A1:E1;QUERY(IFERROR({VLOOKUP(B2:B;G2:H;2;FALSE)\A2:E});"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null Order By Col1 Asc")})`

This one formula produces all results you see.

Some of your information in A2:E will not appear in this list because your countries in Column B do not currently match any countries listed in Column G (e.g., Turquia, Italia, etc.).

**How It Works**

`=ArrayFormula( ... )`

This means that an entire range will be processed, not just one cell.

`{"User"\A1:E1; ... }`

This forms a virtual array with the headers first, followed by the results. "User" is added as a first header to the headers you already have listed in A1:E1.

`QUERY(...);"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null Order By Col1 Asc")`

A `QUERY` will be made of a data set (described below). The `QUERY` will select all rows of the data set where the first column is not empty/null and will sort the remaining results in order of column 1 from lowest to highest. In your case, the User # will be in that first column.

`{VLOOKUP(B2:B;G2:H;2;FALSE)\A2:E}`

This will be the data set that the `QUERY` will act upon. A column will be formed by attempting to look up every country in `B2:B` within `G2:H` and will return the value from the second column of `G2:H` (i.e., the User #). To the right of the User # list will be an exact copy of your `A2:E` data.

`IFERROR( ... )`

Not every country in B2:B will be found in G2:G. This will result in an #NA error for each that is not found. `IFERROR` will replace each #NA error that arises with null. Then, when `QUERY` acts on the set, it will keep only results "Where Col1 Is Not Null."

Comment: Hello Erik, i really was loosing my hope ... because i was trying and trying to get an alternative to get the results i needed. Thank you so much for your help !!! 5*****

Comment: Hello, @Neusa. It sounds like my formula worked for you. Happy to hear it!